# Generalized series expansion for $\Gamma(a,z)$ in $a$ at $a=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I need the generalized series expansion of $\Gamma(a,z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $a\to0^+$. *Mathematica* gives a result that seems to be correct, but I have to make sure of its validity.

I came across [this expansion](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/06/01/01/01/) on *Function Wolfram Research*, but it does not seem to work for the case that I am interested in, namely $a_0 = 0$. It might be possible to take the limit of the seemingly divergent terms (e.g., $\frac{1}{a_0^2}$), and I think that's how *Mathematica* computes the expansion.

I also found an expansion on [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) for $\Gamma(a,x)$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$: [8.7.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7#E3). Although not stated, it seems that it holds only for $a>0$.

The leading term of the expansion of $\Gamma(a,z)$ in $a$ at $a=0$, if exists, should be $\Gamma(0,z)$ which contains a $\log z$ term.

Any thoughts?

Comment: $\Gamma(0,z) =\rm{ Ei_1}(z)$ which is the exponential integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal. Sure, but I don't think it contradicts what I said about the appearance of $\log z$. ([Please see this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#iv)). Am I missing something here?

Comment: So basically you are asking for a Taylor series at the point $a=0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, not its Taylor expansion as it is not analytic. Rather, I am interested in the structure of the non-analytic part of $\Gamma(a,z)$. Specifically, I want to know whether the non-analytic part is of the $log$ form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this expansion

> $$ \Gamma(a,z)={\rm Ei} \left( 1,z \right) + b(z)a + O( a^{2}), $$

where

> $$ b(z) = {\rm Ei} ( 1,z) \ln 
> \left( z \right) + \frac{{\gamma}^{2}}{2}+\ln( z )\gamma + \frac{1}{2}
> ( \ln( z))^{2}+\frac{{\pi }^{2}}{12}-z\,{\mbox{$_3$F$_3$}(1,1,1;\,2,2,2;\,-z)},$$

where $ {\mbox{$_3$F$_3$}(1,1,1;\,2,2,2;\,-z)} $ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please cite a reference? And, what is $_3F_3(\cdots)$?